# Type inference with in operator

Tags: typescript, casting

Typescript doesn't allow infering a type to the object using in-operator.

For example,

```
function getKey<T extends object, U extends string> (obj: T, key: U) {
    if (key in obj) {
        return obj[key] // Type 'U' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
    }
}
```

Typescript should recognize that **U** is **keyof T**, so I could use it as a key.

How can i solve this without the need to using **any**?

Comment: What type are you expecting to pass as `U`? If it is a valid subtype of `string` you could omit it and just have: `getKey<T extends object> (obj: T, key: string) {`. If you want to only use known valid keys, use Titian's answer.

Comment: Fenton, I'd like to allow any key. I'm using in-operator as a flag.

Comment: Can you share a minimal working example of where TypeScript prevents that? I can think of a fix, but want to test it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `U` as extending `keyof T` in order to use it for indexing an object without a `string` indexer.

```
function getKey<T extends object, U extends keyof T> (obj: T, key: U) {
    if (key in obj) {
        return obj[key] // Now works!
    }
}
```

As the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485) for `in` type guards suggest the guard impacts the type of `T` not the type of the key, so you still need to explicitly tell the compiler that `U` extends `keyof T`

If you want to keep `U` as `string` (and I would encourage you to consider if you really need it to be a type parameter and you can't just use `string` for the argument) you can have multiple signatures for the function :

```
// The visible signatures of the function 
// The first one takes keyof T and infers return type based on it
function getKey<T extends object, U extends keyof T> (obj: T, key: U) : T[U]
// The second one takes string and will return any 
function getKey<T extends object> (obj: T, key: string) : any
// The implementation signature allows indexing, this will not be public.
function getKey(obj: { [index: string]: any }, key: string) {
    if (key in obj) {
        return obj[key] // Can now index T
    }
}

let r = getKey({ type: "test"}, "type"); // r is infered to `test`
let r2 = getKey({ type: "test"}, "notAProp"); // r is infered to any
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to limit **key** to **keyof T**, which in itself would already make the in-operator uselless. I'd like to allow any string type.

Comment: Doesn't make it entirely useless, if the property is optional, but I see your point,. I will add an alternative

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to infer the return type?

Comment: @zaclummys Added an overload that types the result based on the property name for cases when this is known at compile time